# Pandas pivot table with very large number of columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-3.5

I have a pandas dataframe `df` with about 1000 rows but 500 columns. The columns are named Run1, Run2, ..., Run500

The existing index is `datetime`.

Sample data from dataframe is as follows:

```
df.ix[1:4,1:4]
                       Run1    Run2    Date
2019-04-01 01:00:00  23.0263  23.0263  2019-04-01
2019-04-01 01:00:00  19.2212  19.2212  2019-04-01
2019-04-02 01:00:00  19.3694  19.3694  2019-04-02
2019-04-02 01:00:00  19.3694  19.3694  2019-04-02
```

I can do the trying the following:

```
pd.pivot_table(df, index=['Date'], values=['Run1'], aggfunc=[np.mean])['mean']
```

But I need to the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
pd.pivot_table(df, index=['Date'], values=['Run1', 'Run2', ...., 'Run500'], aggfunc=[np.mean])['mean']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is `groupby` + `mean`

```
df.groupby('Date').mean()
```